# Unable to access a value from an object in React component

Tags: reactjs, components

> {JSON.stringify(props.db[1]), console.log(props.db[1])}

- props.db is an array of objects [{},{},{}]
- With the following values id,trick and redirect
- {"id":2,"trick":"kickflip","redirect":"http://www.ha.com"}
  When I console.log props.db[1] I get the object that I need but when I try to get a single value out of it doing console.log(props.db[1].id), console.log(props.db[1].trick) or console.log(props.db[1].redirect) i get the error :
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
  To me it makes no sence what is the reason.
  If i do the same while iterating lets say with map it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Its highly likely that at some point in time, `props.db` is empty (i.e. null/undefined or an empty array because its still fetching it asynchronously from the server). You'll need to check its there before rendering:

```
{props.db && props.db.length >= 1 && (JSON.stringify(props.db[1]), console.log(props.db[1]))}
```

That will mean whilst it is empty (i.e. network request still in flight) it wont attempt to access it.

Likely you have the code such that it defaults to empty array `[]` before the network request comes back -- which would explain why `map` works. That will loop over 0 items and therefore execute without incidence, whereas attempting to access the first item of an empty array wont work unless you are sure it exists.

Comment: Yeah it had something to do with the way react renders things. I was attempting to acccess the value before it being populated thank your for your reply :D